# SwiftUI animation not working using animation(_:value:)

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-animation

In SwiftUI, I've managed to make a Button animate right when the view is first drawn to the screen, using the `animation(_:)` modifier, that was deprecated in macOS 12.

I've tried to replace this with the new `animation(_:value:)` modifier, but this time nothing happens:
So this is not working:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isOn = false
    var body: some View {
        Button("Press me") {
            isOn.toggle()
        }
        .animation(.easeIn, value: isOn)
        .frame(width: 300, height: 400)
    }
}
```

But then this is working. Why?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button("Press me") {
        }
        .animation(.easeIn)
        .frame(width: 300, height: 400)
    }
}
```

The second example animates the button just as the view displays, while the first one does nothing

Comment: Needed minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @Asperi well you can use this one: https://github.com/stoiandan/SweetIRC/blob/main/SweetIRC/LoginView.swift

Comment: Are you changing `showChat` when the view appears? Explicit animations watch for a change in the value that is included in the init.

Comment: @Yrb when the Button toggles `showChat`, the whole view is dismissed

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Outside links are discouraged, and we don't need to wade through your whole app. Just make a minimal example that shows your problem.

Comment: @Yrb , added a working example

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The difference between `animation(_:)` and `animation(_:value:)` is straightforward. The former is implicit, and the latter explicit. The implicit nature of `animation(_:)` meant that anytime ANYTHING changed, it would react. The other issue it had was trying to guess what you wanted to animate. As a result, this could be erratic and unexpected. There were some other issues, so Apple has simply deprecated it.

`animation(_:value:)` is an explicit animation. It will only trigger when the value you give it changes. This means you can't just stick it on a view and expect the view to animate when it appears. You need to change the value in an `.onAppear()` or use some value that naturally changes when a view appears to trigger the animation. You also need to have some modifier specifically react to the changed value.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isOn = false
    //The better route is to have a separate variable to control the animations
    // This prevents unpleasant side-effects.
    @State private var animate = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("I don't change.")
                .padding()
            Button("Press me, I do change") {
                isOn.toggle()
                animate = false
                // Because .opacity is animated, we need to switch it
                // back so the button shows.
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                    animate = true
                }
            }
            // In this case I chose to animate .opacity
            .opacity(animate ? 1 : 0)
            .animation(.easeIn, value: animate)
            .frame(width: 300, height: 400)
            // If you want the button to animate when the view appears, you need to change the value
            .onAppear { animate = true }
        }
    }
}
```